# Sort or Seperate large list based into several categories of the elements

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have a large ArrayList of about a thousand elements. These elements are FlashCards for a test. Those FlashCards all belong to one of 13 different categories. How can I split this large collection into different individual lists based on the category ?

Comment: are these categories represented as a variable within the objects?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you without knowing the structure of your data.
Can you provide an example and maybe some code of yours?

Comment: Arraylist of Card objects. Those Card objects have an attribute category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `FlashCard` class with a `getCategory()` method, you can use a stream to collect and group these...

```
// Given a list of FlashCard objects
final List<FlashCard> cards = ...

// Convert to stream, and collect them by category. 
final Map<String, List<FlashCard>> byCategory = cards.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FlashCard::getCategory));
```

The Map now represents the category as the key and each `FlashCard` in that category in a list.

Comment: That looks great! Thats spot on if it'll work, I'm trying to make sure everything comes out correctly right now. One question, what will be the actual type of the Lists used as values ?

Comment: ...Or, how can I make them arraylists. I know nothing about streams. I need to read up on them.

Comment: I see now, if cards is an arraylist the stream will spit out arraylists ?

Comment: The `groupBy` method will give you an implementation of list, you shouldn't need to worry about the specific type. Once you get a category out, you can do this...  `List<FlashCard> java = byCategory.get("Java");`. If you code to the interface rather than implementation, it's easier.

Comment: @madmax - Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your flash card has an attribute `Type` like

```
class FlashCard {
    private Type myType;
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyDevice [myType=" + myType + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

    public FlashCard(Type myType, String name) {
        this.myType = myType;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Type getMyType() {
        return myType;
    }

    public void setMyType(Type myType) {
        this.myType = myType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

enum Type {
    ONE, TWO, NONE
}
```

then you can map those as:

```
List<FlashCard> lisOfDevices = new ArrayList<>();
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.ONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.ONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.TWO, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.ONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.ONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.TWO, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.TWO, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.NONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));
lisOfDevices.add(new FlashCard(Type.NONE, UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 4)));

Map<Type, List<FlashCard>> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();
lisOfDevices.stream().map(FlashCard::getMyType).distinct().forEach(id -> categoryMap.put(id,
        lisOfDevices.stream().filter(object -> id.equals(object.getMyType())).collect(Collectors.toList())));

// print it
System.out.println(categoryMap.size());
System.out.println(categoryMap);
```